# Turn horizontal Superfish menu into dropdown on small screens

Tags: jquery, superfish

I have a Superfish-enabled horizontal menu that I would like to turn into a dropdown menu when the window loads at—or is resized to—less than 800 pixels wide. I would like that dropdown to return to a horizontal list if the window is resized to more than 800 pixels.

The horizontal menu looks like this, output via PHP (simplified here):

```
<ul id="menu-primary">
        <li id="menu-item-683">...</li>
        <li id="menu-item-10">
         <a class="sf-with-ul" href="about-us">About Us</a>
         <ul class="sub-menu"> </ul>
        </li>
        ...
</ul>
```

So I tried wrapping the menu like this:

```
$("#menu-primary").wrap("<ul id='menu-dropdown' class='sf-menu sf-vertical'><li id='li_drop' class='menu-item'></li></ul>");
$("#menu-primary").before("<span id='nav-dropdown' class='sf-with-ul'>MENU</span>");
```

And then calling superfish on the wrapper for smaller window sizes, and simply removing the superfish classes from the wrapper for larger window sizes with this:

```
    function menudrop(){
if ( $(window).innerWidth() < 800) {
    $("#menu-dropdown").addClass("menu menu-dropdown superfish sf-js-enabled");
    $('#menu-dropdown').superfish({delay:100,animation:{height:'show'},dropShadows: false, speed: 1});
}

else {
    $("#menu-dropdown").removeClass("menu menu-dropdown superfish sf-js-enabled");
}
}
```

It mostly works, but if I load the page at <800 pixels and resize to >800, `#menu-primary` doesn't show. I've tried making the CSS exactly the same as if I hadn't added the wrapper, but it doesn't work. It seems that I need to undo `$('#menu-dropdown').superfish();` somehow, but I don't know how to do that.

Is this possible, or is there a better way of accomplishing this idea (without converting the menu to a `<select><option>...` menu)?

Answer (score 0):

Superfish must have a jquery event bound to the menu, so even when you change the html to exactly the old one, it might change the drop-down effect but it would still be buggy. Superfish effect is not reversible (I think) but you can define 2 styles for the same css on the drop-down menu, one you already have is #menu-primary, and make another one #menu-primary2 (or anything else), these two styles should be exactly the same. Before applying the superfish effect, save the old menu html:

```
var oldmenu = $('#menu-primary').html();
$('#menu-primary').superfish(....
```

Then on browser size > 800 paste back the old html:

```
$('#menu-primary').html(oldmenu);
```

And apply the other class (with same styles) like this:

```
$('#menu-primary').attr("id", "menu-primary2");
```

Now the superfish effect wont work on this menu and the styles are still the same.